# Infer a K-multinomial mixture model from "group-less" data

Tags: multinomial-distribution, mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

I want to infer a multinomial mixture model consisting of $K$ components where each component has the same number of trials, denoted as $N$. Such a multinomial mixture model can be written as:
$$
\mathsf{M}(x; \pi_{1:K}, p_{1:K}) = \sum_{k = 1}^{K} \pi_{k} \mathrm{Mult}(x; N, p_{k}),
$$
where $K$ and $N$ are given, $\pi_{k}$ is the mixture coefficient of component $k$-th and $p_{k}$ is the probability vector for component $k$-th.

To infer $\{(\pi_{k}, p_{k})\}_{k = 1}^{K}$, a naive way is to collect $m$ data points, each is an $N$-trial samples and use the Expectation - Maximization (EM) algorithm. Instead of collecting $m$ $N$-trial data points, I, however, mix those data points and obtain $m \times N$ 1-trial data points. In other words, I lose the grouping information. I wonder if there is a way to infer the mixture model $M(x; \pi_{1:K}, p_{1:K})$ from those mixed data points.

Any suggestions or references to any research papers are appreciated.